# Having trouble removing certain items from list c#

Tags: c#, list, date

So I'm building a meeting scheduler, in which each potential participant has a set of unavailable dates. For the sake of testing I inserted my own.

The user enters a date range, which is then put into a list of all the dates in-between.

I currently have a list of unavailable dates depending on who the user has invited to the event. This is saved into a list called unavailableDates.

I'm trying to delete all the dates that exist in the datesBetween list that are also in the unavailableDates list, to leave only dates that aren't on a persons unavailable dates.

I've tried a few different things but i cant seem to get it working.

```
private void compileDates()
    {
        DateTime startingDate = cal1.SelectionEnd;                                                  //Get the starting date from the first calender
        DateTime endingDate = cal2.SelectionEnd;                                                    //Get the ending date from the first calender

        var namesList = lstConfirmedParticipants.Items.Cast<String>().ToList();                     //Collects all the participants names and converts it to a list

        List<DateTime> PhillChambers = new List<DateTime>();                                        //Set Pauls Unavailable Dates
        PhillChambers.Add(new DateTime(2014, 08, 11));
        PhillChambers.Add(new DateTime(2014, 08, 12));
        PhillChambers.Add(new DateTime(2014, 08, 17));

        List<DateTime> HenryWright = new List<DateTime>();                                          //Set Pauls Unavailable Dates
        HenryWright.Add(new DateTime(2014, 08, 09));
        HenryWright.Add(new DateTime(2014, 08, 12));
        HenryWright.Add(new DateTime(2014, 08, 14));

        List<DateTime> PaulaCooper = new List<DateTime>();                                          //Set Pauls Unavailable Dates
        PaulaCooper.Add(new DateTime(2014, 08, 11));
        PaulaCooper.Add(new DateTime(2014, 08, 12));
        PaulaCooper.Add(new DateTime(2014, 08, 16));

        List<DateTime> unavailableDates = new List<DateTime>();                                     //Creates a new list to hold all the unavailable dates            

        if (namesList.Contains("Paula Cooper"))
        {                                                                                           //Add Paulas Unavailable Dates
            unavailableDates.AddRange(PaulaCooper);
        }
        if (namesList.Contains("Henry Wright"))
        {                                                                                           //Add Henrys Unavailable Dates
            unavailableDates.AddRange(HenryWright);
        }
        if (namesList.Contains("Phill Chambers"))
        {                                                                                           //Add Phills Unavailable Dates
            unavailableDates.AddRange(PhillChambers);
        }

        foreach (DateTime date in GetDateRange(startingDate, endingDate))
        {
            lstDatesBetween.Items.Add(date.ToShortDateString());                                    //Get all the dates between the date ranges and put them into the listbox.
        }

        List<DateTime> datesBetween = lstDatesBetween.Items.OfType<DateTime>().ToList();            //Convert the Listbox into a list holding all the dates between the date ranges

        datesBetween.RemoveAll(item => unavailableDates.Contains(item));                            //remove all the dates in dates between that also appear in unavailable dates

        List<DateTime> availableDates = new List<DateTime>();                                       //Creates a new list to hold all the available dates(FUTURE USE)

        availableDates.AddRange (datesBetween); 

        lstDatesAvailable.DataSource = availableDates;                                              //display the available dates for the meeting




private List<DateTime> GetDateRange(DateTime StartingDate, DateTime EndingDate)
   {
       if (StartingDate > EndingDate)
       {
           return null;
       }
       List<DateTime> datesBetween = new List<DateTime>();
       DateTime tempDate = StartingDate;
       do
       {
           datesBetween.Add(tempDate);
           tempDate = tempDate.AddDays(1);
       } while (tempDate <= EndingDate);
       return datesBetween;
   }
```

Comment: what does the debugger say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `lstDatesBetween` is populated with strings:

```
lstDatesBetween.Items.Add(date.ToShortDateString());
```

and then `datesBetween` takes elements of type `DateTime`:

```
List<DateTime> datesBetween = lstDatesBetween.Items.OfType<DateTime>().ToList();
```

So I guess `datesBetween` is empty.

Try if this works:

```
List<DateTime> datesBetween = lstDatesBetween.Items
                                  .OfType<string>()
                                  .Select(s => Convert.ToDateTime(s))
                                  .ToList();
```

Comment: Yeah i see now, i was getting confused as i had the dates displaying previously.

Thanks!